# Laravel API read parameters from URL

Tags: api, laravel, laravel-4

I have an application which reads data from an external application.

Data is send to my application in following form

http://localhost/public/checkout?amount=110&name=test

There is no authentication done or required, as we verify the source & data via a checksum validation. This is how the parent API works and need to follow the same way.

In the route i am redirecting checkout URL to a controller function, in the controller, how do i read this data from URL? This doesn't work.

```
Input::get('amount');
```

Route looks like this

```
  Route::post('/checkout',array('as'=>'postcheckout','uses'=>'CheckoutController@postData'));
```

**I am currently getting following error**

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: Just looking at this, you are registering the route as a POST request, but calling it as a GET request. Does that impact the input array Laravel builds?

Comment: Your route is setup to accept POST requests. Make sure your request is POST. Also I can see you have url parameters present in you route which gives me hint that you are trying to access it by GET method. Just change in your router: 'Route::get(...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Route::get(...)` instead :) that shoud do the trick